# PHP cURL POST Returns bool(false)

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem in my code and I want your help
I have this site that makes an IPTV account

http://thgss.com/

This site depends on three pages before it can be downloaded
On the second page "http://thgss.com/index.php?p=download2" and after entering the captcha code.

**POST request** is sent to 'http://thgss.com/index.php?p=download3'

With the following data : 'done=true&submit=Download+Now'

**request header**

```
POST /index.php?p=download3 HTTP/1.1
Host: thgss.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 29
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://thgss.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://thgss.com/index.php?p=download2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ar,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=imbdp791tqal3fq8ifa80till1
done=true&submit=Download+Now
```

The m3u file link is in the **reply header** in location

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2018 04:56:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
location: http://24.thgss.com:8000/get.php?username=37441545108977&password=37441545108977&type=m3u&output=mpegts
Content-Length: 2584
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

My code works well on the **local server**

But when you upload it to remote server show"**bool(false)**" error

I want you to help me **check my** code

**my code**

```
function getUserIP() {
    if( array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ) {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], ',')>0) {
            $addr = explode(",",$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
            return trim($addr[0]);
        } else {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
    }
    else {
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}
$ip = getUserIP() ;

$data = 'done=true&submit=Download+Now';
$headers = array(
    $data,
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Referer: http://thgss.com/index.php?p=download2',
    'X-Forwarded-For: '. $ip
);

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://thgss.com/index.php?p=download3');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

> help me get location url from reply header

You need to get info from your Curl request, and get the header from there.

Here is your code:

```
$ip = getUserIP() ;

$data = 'done=true&submit=Download+Now';
$headers = array(
    $data,
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Referer: http://thgss.com/index.php?p=download2',
    'X-Forwarded-For: '. $ip
);

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://thgss.com/index.php?p=download3');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
var_dump($response);
```

Before your `curl_close`, add the following:

```
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($curl_handle);
```

You can then use `preg_match` to find your location header:

```
$headers = substr($response, 0, $curl_info["header_size"]);
preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $headers, $location);
```

You should then find your Location header in `$location`, probably `$location[1]`.

On a side note, is that the user's Username and Password you're sending in the header?

**Edit:**

Since the original question has been changed since I answered this, I am now editing my answer.

To help you debug any errors with the actual curl request, before `curl_close` you can add:

```
$errs = curl_error($curl_handle);
```

`$errs` will now provide you with any reasons the curl request may be failing. An example error is:

> "Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates"

You can read more in the docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

**Edit 2:**

After you said you have a timeout issue,I now notice that you have used 2 seconds:
`curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);`...

Try increasing your timeout:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30); 
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
```

You can also use `0` which is to wait indefinitely.

Comment: thanks @Jonathan but whay i get bool(false) on remot server
tray this [link](http://2019.gq/tv3lpc/serv/thgss.php)

Comment: i didnt send Username or Password just tha data in the code

Comment: You have edited your question, and you are no longer asking "help me get location url from reply header" which is what I answered. Anyway, If it works locally and not on your remote server, there's probably something different in your php configs. Have you tried using `echo phpinfo();` to compare?

Comment: I've edited my answer to help you, try using `$errs = curl_error($curl_handle);` to get any errors from curl.

Comment: im sorry But it was running on the remote server and is no longer working and will not be anything else. The code was working without problems

Comment: i use curl_error and get Connection timed out after 2001 milliseconds

Comment: I've edited my answer again, try increasing your timeout.

Comment: @ Jonathan sorry still sam error Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds i dont know what's the Wrong [link](http://2019.gq/tv3lpc/serv/thgss.php)